# Permalink Problem with Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

First Please open this link: `http://www.infoproductexpert.com` .

Now you will find Multiple category in the left panel.

I have created a custom post_type. This `post_type` name is "**product**". Under this `post_type` I have added category under each product. So that as per product, I can separate the link.

***Requirement 1***

If you click any category, it is showing something like this: `http://www.infoproductexpert.com/category/green-energy-products/`

But I want to change this to `http://www.infoproductexpert.com/green-energy-products/` . Thats mean, I do not want to show this `post_type`.

***Requirement 2***

Also if you click any product under each category, it is showing something like this: `http://www.infoproductexpert.com/product/diy-home-energy/` . But I want to see this : `http://www.infoproductexpert.com/green-energy-products/diy-home-energy/`. It's meaning product must be showing under each category and do not want to show `post_type` here also.

Can anyone please help me, how can I do this?

This is really important to me.

Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

To remove category from your URL do:

1. Go to Setting > Permalinks
2. Select Custom Structure
3. Add /%category%/%postname%/ after your domain
4. Change Category Base to period/dot.

Read this blog https://jonnyjordan.com/blog/how-to-remove-category-from-your-urls-in-wordpress/[image]

Comment: You can't remove category base this way, any pagination beyond the first page will 404.